# UITableView with 3 Sections - Update ForRow 0 und Section 0 direct from a function

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have 3 sections in my UITableView. The first one has a style Right Details style and only 1 row. The second and third has a Custome style and dynamic rows.

I would like to update in the 1st section the detailTextLabel from a function.

```
let idx = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)!
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellServerStatus", forIndexPath: idx) as! UITableViewCell
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Connected"
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

But nothing happened with the label. The function is in the main class.

What do I wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Sven

Answer (score 1):

You are changing only the label of the cell and then you call `reloadData()` which immediately retrieves the original value from the table's datasource.

You need to change the value in the datasource.

Answer (score -1):

What you have done is not for updating the content of your tableView in the screen but it modify a cell that is not in your table view.

You have 2 options:

Modify directly:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
if let cell =  self.tblMain.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
     //do your work with cell
}
```

- Update the string to Connected then call `reloadData` on your table view, then in the call-back `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, setup your cell with that string.